# Не считывает данные файлов

Tags: файлы, php

При помощи такой функции считываю данные о файлах.

```
$d = "../files";
$dh = opendir( $d ) or die ( "Не удалось открыть каталог $d" );
while ( $f = readdir( $dh ) ) {
    if(($f != '.') && ($f != '..')) {
        $f = strtolower($f);
        $size = round(filesize($f)/1024);
        $lastcng = date("d.m.Y", filectime($f));
    }
}
closedir($d);
```

В папке files находится и файл с кодом. Её он считывает нормально. Однако если написать другую папку, выше или ниже расположенную, то выводятся только имена, а размер выходит 0, и дата создания какая-то непонятная.

В чём может быть проблема? Права вроде нормально стоят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

писано-переписано и все от лени, на [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.readdir.php#109132) зайдите, там куча примеров КАК обходить директории. `$f` содержит ИМЯ файла в открытой директории. оно НЕ содержит путь до этого файла. хотите использовать это имя в других функциях -- добавьте ДИРЕКТОРИЮ где он лежит...

Comment: Да точно путь забыл, спасибо большое!

Comment: И  strtolower() уберите.